# Problem in exceuting specific code in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, class, variables, spyder, python-3.7

I am using Spyder IDE. I have a below line in my code :

```
if (isinstance(signalsInExcelFile[i-1]['aufloesung'], str)):
```

which **sometimes** gives me error when I run the code. The error is :

> TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

But after **restarting** the IDE the error is gone and my code gets executed successfully. Is the problem with  the IDE or there is something with this specific line of code which is producing this error?

Comment: I experience strange behaviours in spider sometimes, but you should expand your code to allow reproducing the issue.

Comment: what do you mean by expanding the code? which IDE would you suggest for python?

Comment: I mean give the example of code from start to end, so we could reproduce issue. I use PyCharm now, there is free community version out there.